# Azure virtual machine - Purpose of Storage account

Tags: azure

I'm looking for the purpose of a Storage account in Azure. Because I have a problem with.

My account is limited to 1 Storage account, and apparently I'm already using it, but I don't know why, I don't think I need it.

I have one virtual machine with a cloud service and the storage account. I would like to create another virtual machine but I can't because of the Storage account limit.

May I delete the Storage accout? I don't want to break my virtual machine.

Few months ago, I was able to create two virtual machines, so I don't understand why I can't anymore, my Azure account didn't change. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage Account is "the storage" where Azure puts your Virtual Machine disks (=vhd files).
On the same Storage Account you can create more than one Virtual Machine.

[image: How to choose the storage account]

Comment: Yeah, I think too, but when I want to create a new virtual machine, I don't choose to create a new Storage account, I got a cancelation because he can't create a new Storage account.

Comment: I'm trying to use another way to create it, but still the same, I can't choose to use an existing Storage account, I only have one choice that is to create a new Storage account...

Comment: I edited my answer with one screenshot. There you can choose an existing storage account.

Comment: I have the same view but only one choice. Use an automatically generated storage account, nothing else, that's why I can't chose! Weird!

Comment: I found why! It's because I HAVE to choose the existing Cloud service and not use the default choice!